# 3x2x2 mixed design: data modelling/analysis and sample size

Tags: anova, mixed-model, sample-size

**Background:**

I'm planning an experiment with three independent variables (IV) and one dependent variable (DV) and would like to get an idea of what methods of data analysis might be appropriate and what corresponding sample size I should aim for.

**Detailed:**
Each participant completes three scenarios (IV "Scenario") in a fixed time. The proportion of time participants look in area-of-interest(AOI)1 and not in AOI2 is assessed (DV). I want to find out whether the change in this proportion from scenario 1 (s1) to scenario 3 (s3) depends on the (interaction-)effects of two other DVs (B and C).

Hypotheses 1 ("Scenario"): The proportion of time participants look in AOI1 increases significantly from s1 to s3.

Hypotheses 2 ("Scenario"x"Intervention1"): The proportion of time participants look in AOI1 increases significantly from s1 to s3. *This effect is significantly smaller for "Intervention1"=1 than for "Intervention1"=0.*

Hypotheses 3 ("Scenario"x"Intervention1"x"Intervention2"): The proportion of time participants look in AOI1 increases significantly from t1 to t3. This effect is significantly smaller for "Intervention1"=1 than for "Intervention1"=0. *This effect (=reduction of main effect "Scenario") is significantly smaller for "Intervention2" = 1 than for "Intervention2"=0.*

**IVs:**
"Scenario": 3 levels/times of measurement(s1 - s3), repeated measure/within-subject, not randomized
"Intervention 1": 2 levels (0 = no intervention; 1= intervention applied), between-subject
"Intervention 2": 2 levels (0 = no intervention; 1= intervention applied), between-subject

**DV:**
Y: continuous, percentage (0-100%).

I'm most interested in the three-way interaction ("Scenario"x"Intervention1"x"Intervention2").

As far as I can tell, the DV's data might not suit the requirements for normal distribution for an ANOVA since data is bounded 0 and 100, respectively. The data model might assume data outside the possible scale.

**Question 1:** Assuming DV's data varies between 20% and 80%. Is the limited scale still a problem or might an ANOVA work just fine?

**Question 2:** What other data modelling + data analysis method is (more) appropriate?

**Question 3:** How can I determine the ideal sample size for (a) an ANOVA or (b) another - more appropriate - analysis (log regression, tobit,...) for this 3x2x2 mixed design?

I tried to provide all necessary details but I'm everything but an expert in this field. Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: welcome to the site. please clarify your key hypotheses  under detailed. Also name variables.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Thank you. I edited my post accordingly. Does this clear things up?

Comment: Is it a self-study  problem that you are planning ? Indicate how will you go for Anova design ? what are your DVs etc.